# Android WebView shows a blank page When play Html with iframe

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I am trying html file to show inside WebView in android,bu When I try it, I see black screen at my android phone, Html has iframe

Html code

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="webPage" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>


<script>
    var Url, Interval;

    function init() {
        document.getElementById('webPage').setAttribute('src', Url);
    }
    function setParams(params) {
        //console.log(params);
        params.forEach(element => {
            switch (element.key) {
                case "Url":
                Url = element.value;
                    break;
                case "Interval":
                Interval = element.value;
                    break;
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('webPage').setAttribute('src', Url);

        setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById('webPage').setAttribute('src', Url);
        }, (Interval * 60 * 1000));
    }

    function listener(event) {
        setParams(event.data);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('message', listener, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) { // ie8
        window.attachEvent('onmessage', listener);
    }

    function deleteContent()
```

{
     try
     {
        var el = document.getElementById('webPage');
        el.setAttribute('src',"about:blank");
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     }
     catch(err)
     {
        console.log("Web Page Delete ERROR:"+err);
     }
}

Android Code

```
browser.setInitialScale(60);
//WebView browser = new WebView(context);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/index.html");
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientCustomPoster());
//((Activity) context).setContentView(browser);
WebSettings ws = browser.getSettings();
ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
ws.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
ws.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
ws.setAllowContentAccess(true);
ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @SuppressLint("SyntheticAccessor")
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        // do your stuff here
        JSONObject userData = new JSONObject();

        try {
            userData.put("PlayerCode", CommonUseFunc.getJsonText("Player","PlayerCode"));
            userData.put("PrivateKey",CommonUseFunc.getJsonText("Player","PrivateKey"));
            userData.put("PublicKey",CommonUseFunc.getJsonText("Player","PublicKey"));
            userData.put("Api",CommonUseFunc.getJsonText("General","ApplicationServer","API"));
            userData.put("VideoMode","0");
            userData.put("BasePath", Objects.requireNonNull(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JSONObject jsonObjectInit = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObjectInit.put("MessageType","init");
            jsonObjectInit.put("Data",userData);

            browser.evaluateJavascript("javascript:PIXAGE.Platform.WebMethod.receiveMessage('" + jsonObjectInit + "')",
                    null);

            Utils.logProcess(Utils.timeInfo(), "StartManager", "initialize Web View", 0);

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utils.logProcess(Utils.timeInfo(), "StartManager", "initialize Web View Eror", 1);
        }


        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(getPublishment);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jsonObject.put("Guid",1111);
            jsonObject.put("MessageType","newPublishment");
            jsonObject.put("Data",obj);

            browser.evaluateJavascript("javascript:PIXAGE.Platform.WebMethod.receiveMessage('" + jsonObject + "')",
                    null);

            Utils.logProcess(Utils.timeInfo(), "StartManager", "Data Sended", 0);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utils.logProcess(Utils.timeInfo(), "StartManager", "Data Sended Eror", 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -->

make a custom web view :

```
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}}
```

include it your xml(in place of webview):

```
 <com........TouchyWebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    />
```

add this in activity :

```
ws.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"file:///android_asset/index.html", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    WebSettings settings = ws.getSettings();
    WebSettings webSetting = ws.getSettings();

    webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ws.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    ws.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    ws.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
     ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     ws.setAllowContentAccess(true);
     ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```